# iOS - How to get GATT handle of a given characteristic in CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, gatt

I need to access a custom BLE GATT service that contains multiple instances of same characteristic. It sounds weird but complies with v4.0 standard (Vol.3, Part G, Sec 3.3.1):

> A service may have multiple characteristic definitions with the same Characteristic UUID.

The first characteristic of this service is a list of [CustomID:GattHandle] pairs that represent the identity and position of the following characteristics. A GATT client is supposed to first discover all characteristics and then read the the value of ID:handle list, so that the identity of each characteristics shall be known.

The problem is, `CBCharacteristic` class doesn't provide GATT handle of characteristic. And I can't find any information whether `CBService.characteristics` will follow the nature order of attribute handle in GATT server.

Is there anyway to acquire the GATT handle of a given `CBCharacteristic` object ?

Comment: Let me know few things. 1. Which is your target device ? 2. Target Bluetooth Version . 3. What data you are trying to send.

Comment: Have you looked at the characteristic's `descriptors` array?

Comment: Vineesh: The target device is a TI CC2650 Dev Kit from another department of my company. We're working  on the same project. I believe they're using the new released TI-BLE stack 3.0.0, which support BLE 4.2. The characteristic data are an measurements of multiple accelerometers (we have up to six 3-axis accelerometers attached to the BLE module via cables). That's why they are using multiple instances of same characteristic within one service.

Comment: Paulw11: It's our own developed custom profile and we don't assign descriptor to these characteristics, except for the CCCD for notification. Besides, I believe that the CBDescriptor doesn't provide GATT handle information either.

Comment: I am pretty sure the list follows the same order as the handles.

Comment: @RichardLiu did you get any solution for GATT?

Comment: @RATHOD Nope. We decide to add a descriptor to each characteristic for identification.